# List of child publications

Tags: core-service

Is there any property or method to get the list of child publications of a particular publication using core service?

Thanks,
Jey

Comment: Yes, there is http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4988/how-to-get-the-list-of-child-publications-from-parent-publications-using-coreser

Comment: I have cheked the post. when i pass the Publicatio ID/webdav url. It throws an error as "Publicatin" type not expected.

Comment: Please update your question with the code snippet you tried. And the error you are getting.

Comment: I'd wager that in that's because the post uses `filter.ForItem` (i.e. page/component) where you need to use `filter.ForRepository` for the publication?

Answer (score 1):

As per my [answer in this previous question](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/11428/25), "Where Used" is your friend.

```
client.GetList(publicationId, new UsingItemsFilterData());
```

gives you a list of items which "use" the publication, i.e. it's children.

The list will include all of the descendant publications. If you want only the direct children then you can loop over each publication in the list and check it's parents. See my other [answer](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/11428/25) for an example of how to do that.