# Search All components in Folder and Child publication

Tags: core-service, 2013-sp1

I am searching for a way to find all components in a folder and in the folders of the child publication. So for example:

`tcm:0-5-1  folder tcm:5-10-2
 |-->tcm:0-6-1 folder tcm:6-10-2
 |-->tcm:0-7-1 folder tcm:7-10-2`

Than I would like a way, through Core Service, to get all components in tcm:5-10-2, tcm:6-10-2 and tcm:7-10-2 by just knowing tcm:5-10-2.

I have tried using *GetList* with *BluePrintChainFilterData* with *Direction.Down* to get all child folders but I only got tcm:5-10-2.

Any idea on how to tackle this one?

Thanks!

Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

1. Get the child Publications of the Publication (using [where used](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4988/how-to-get-the-list-of-child-publications-from-parent-publications-using-coreser/11428#11428))
2. Loop through the Publications.
3. Get the local folder id for the Publication

   `var localId = tridionClient.GetTcmUri(objectID, publicationID, null);`
4. Extract the Components from the local Folder and collect them in a collection.