# fetch publication structure using core-services (java)

Tags: core-service, java, sdl-tridion

I want to fetch publication structure using core-services (java) from SDL Trdion13. what i need to do for this?

Comment: What have you tried? E.g. Look in docs, Google, read blogs, do a code POC, etc. Please put some effort into your question before asking others to put effort into answering.

Comment: Welcome to Tridion Stack Exchange. As Nick says, it will make for a much better question if you can add some of that detail. Our goal here is to ensure that both questions and answers are useful not only to the people directly involved, but also to the wider community. Many people will read your question and the answers it gets, so it makes sense to ensure that it's fit for purpose. That said, there are plenty of people willing to help. So - please, expand on your question, and we'll see where we get to.

Answer (score 2):

Given your question is rather vague... here's my best answer:

1. You need to find a way to connect to Core Service from Java. Either generate a proxy from the wsdl as [documented here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-CF2ABF27-2D1C-4342-9635-2DFD7A6D4D42) or use a pre-built one from the [community](http://mihaiconsulting.com/projects/core-service-java)
2. Ask Tridion for a list of publications using the Core Service API, using something similar to [this](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4988/how-to-get-the-list-of-child-publications-from-parent-publications-using-coreser)
3. Ask additional questions based on where you get stuck.