# Publication levels

Tags: core-service, blueprint, publication

In the content manager, we can see publications blueprinting hierarchy. When we right-click on publication, select blueprinting -> blueprinting hierarchy, we can see publications by levels in the popup.

Is there a way to do this via CoreService? Or I need to read the list of publications, and then use information about their parents and build a tree by myself?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is a filter called `Tridion.ContentManager.Data.ContentManagement.BluePrintNodesFilterData` or 
        `Tridion.ContentManager.Data.ContentManagement.BluePrintParentsFilterData`.
You should be able to use one of these filters in combination with the `GetSystemWideList` function.

This filter allows you to set the "ForRepository" property, which should be the ID of a publication. With this filter, you should get all parent publications of this publication.

For all properties of this filter, take a look at the Core Service documentation (chm) file. You can download this file in the SDL documentation site (https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-74C197CB-6F91-424E-9FE6-19E8544EBECF)

Comment: I try to use this filters, but as result I have publications sorted by tcm uri.

Comment: I believe you can than loop through the results and us the parents property. Alternatively, check this question and the different answers. There are some other suggestions in there as well.
https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4988/how-to-get-the-list-of-child-publications-from-parent-publications-using-coreser

Answer (score 0):

This code will be useful if anybody needs to get publications in blueprint order

```
public List<PublicationData> getPublicationsInBlueprintOrder(List<PublicationData> publications) {
    int size = publications.size();
    List<PublicationData> orderedPublications = new ArrayList<>(size);
    HashSet<String> addedUris = new HashSet<>(size);

    while(orderedPublications.size() < size) {

        List<PublicationData> lastAdded = new ArrayList<>();

        for (PublicationData p : publications) {
            if(isRoot(p) || allParentsFound(p, addedUris)) {
                orderedPublications.add(p);
                addedUris.add(p.getId());
            }
        }

        publications.removeAll(lastAdded);
        lastAdded.clear();
    }

    return orderedPublications;
}



private static boolean allParentsFound(PublicationData publication, HashSet<String> addedUris) {
    if(isRoot(publication)) {
        return true;
    }

    List<String> parentsUris = publication.getParents()
                                          .getLinkToRepositoryData()
                                          .stream()
                                          .map(Link::getIdRef)
                                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return addedUris.containsAll(parentsUris);
}

private static boolean isRoot(PublicationData publication) {
    return isNull(publication.getParents()) || publication.getParents().getLinkToRepositoryData().isEmpty();
}
```